# What are the current statistics of the flu globally since December 2019 until today?

Tags: statistics, influenza, virus

I can only find the current statistics for the US that says "Between 36 million and 51 million people have been stricken with the flu as of March 7, according to the latest CDC data." Source: https://www.advisory.com/daily-briefing/2020/03/17/flu-update

I would like to know the global statistics of how many flu cases there are in the world since December 2019 until today.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.who.int/influenza/gisrs_laboratory/updates/summaryreport/en/

That gives testing data which is updated regularly. You can download the data to aggregate yourself.

Comment: Thanks i found that link before but i cant figure out what the global number is TODAY and if we set the timeframe to december 2019 until today, if you could help me with this i would be super happy.

Comment: Consider it homework

Comment: @AndyLjunggren You don't even have to download the data and do it yourself. The site allows you to select a custom time period and does it for you. This is a solid answer to your question.

Comment: I tried to do it but i could not read it correctly, i need the numbers spelled out for me, maybe you could help me? and type in december 2019 until present day today and give me the global numbers of cases?, would be very glad if i got these numbers.